# how to change video orientation in MediaRecorder to portrait

Tags: android, video-recording, device-orientation, mediarecorder

When I record video by MediaRecorder, it always records in landscape mode, regardless of real device orientation.
How to force MediaRecorder/Camera use real orientation ?

Comment: what about set `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` of your CameraActivity in the manifest

Answer (score 20):

refer to [Camera.Parameters.setRotation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation%28int%29) for more information.

There is an example there and instead of calling `setRotation(rotation)` try to call `mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(rotation)` when recording video.

Comment: `mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint` only changes the orientation of the output video, not the orientation of the preview.

Comment: In addition, `setOrientationHint` only works for MPEG4 streams. Others (like MPEG2TS) do not implement this option (it gets silently ignored).

Comment: @Cat you are right, any idea about how to fix that on the preview ?!!

Comment: @ Lekensteyn how to apply setOrientationHint() for MPEG2TS format while recording video.

Comment: Note the setOrientationHint only works for 2 formats: "OutputFormat.MPEG_4" and "OutputFormat.THREE_GPP". more info at : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#setOrientationHint(int)

Answer (score 16):

Add the following two lines of code:

```
Camera.setDisplayOrientation(90); // use for set the orientation of the preview
mRecorder.setOrientationHint(90); // use for set the orientation of output video
```

before:

```
mRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
```

Full example:

```
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

// Both are required for Portrait Video
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
mRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);

// Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
mCamera.unlock();
mRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

// Step 2: Set sources
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);

// Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
mRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P));
```

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the documentation here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video

The most common pitfall with the this example is the setCamera() .   YOU MUST SET THE CAMERA IMMEDIATELY AFTER MAKING THE MediaRecorder otherwise you will get errors.

```
    Camera mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    // adjust the camera the way you need
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

    MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    mCamera.unlock();
    recorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
    recorder.setOutputFile(filePath);

    // add any limits
    recorder.setMaxDuration(50000); // 50 seconds
    recorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Approximately 5 megabytes
```

I hope this helps someone. Good Luck!!

Comment: this code will fail UNLESS you call `mCamera.unlock();` before `recorder.setCamera(mCamera)`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#unlock()

Answer (score 4):

```
 mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mServiceCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
        mServiceCamera.unlock();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mServiceCamera);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
```

Answer (score 3):

I've stuck with this problem before, too. I found that you can use the function [setOrientationHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setOrientationHint%28int%29) (API 9). Call this function before you call MediaRecorder.prepare(). You can setup the orientation degree for your output video.

Hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: doesn't actually rotate the video to correct orientation, it's just a flag that is set to video which some mediaplayers like vlc ignore.