# Can you recording video with a rotation using Camera2 and Camera api in android?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder, android-camera2

without `setOrientationHint`

I'm trying to record video using the `mediaRecorder` on `Camera` and `Camera2`.

I need to combine multiple mp4 recordings from the front and the back camera. I'm doing this with the `media4mobile` library.

The problem is that "joining" videos together strips out the orientation hint metadata. As the front and back cameras on almost all android devices are oriented in the opposite direction, the results in a video that is upside-down for all videos taken from one source.

Is there a way of recording video at a rotation, that rotates every frame, and doesn't just apply meta-data.

Does anyone know of a encoding library that handles rotation ? I've looked at FFmpeg but cannot use it because of licensing issues.

Comment: refer to upvoted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901053/how-to-change-video-orientation-in-mediarecorder-to-portrait

Comment: Thank you for your time but this is covering a different problem. I cannot use setOrientationHint.